# Select control not initializing when using sub object

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, meanjs

I can't seem to get a dropdown full of objects to initialize to current value.

HTML dropdown

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="stat">Stat</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select ng-options="stat as stat.name for stat in statList" data-ng-model="badge.stat" id="stat" class="form-control" >
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

statList is a list of objects that have been loaded via

```
$scope.statList = Stats.query();
```

The badge has stat as a subobject it gets loaded via

```
Badge.findById(id).populate('stat').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, badge) { ...
```

When the select loads I assume that badge.stat should match something in the list. It doesn't seem to . the values on the badge.stat seem to be set I can get the id, and other fields fine.
Ithink there might be some subtle difference between an object loaded by query and an object loaded by .populate.  How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a subtle difference between the objects, they are different objects. Angular compares the references and the are not equal. If you want to identify the objects by some unique value you can use `track by`:

```
ng-options="stat as stat.name for stat in statList track by stat.name"
```

This example assumes that the names are unique.